# How to push objectIds' array to RelationshipQuery's object in ArcGIS API JavaScript 4.9?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, query, relationship-class, relates, array

I need to push array of the object IDs to [RelationshipQuery's object](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-tasks-support-RelationshipQuery.html) using [executeForIds](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-tasks-QueryTask.html#executeForIds) that generates the array. I also used [executeRelationshipQuery](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-tasks-QueryTask.html#executeRelationshipQuery) that executes the query. I don't not why, but *executeForIds* executes after the *executeRelationshipQuery*, so objectIds array in *RelationshipQuery* is empty. Can anyone advise me how to push all objectIds to array? Everything works fine when I push the array to *RelationshipQuery* manually without *executeForIds* (queryRel.objectIds = [1,2,3,...]).
Here is my code:

```
 var queryTask = new QueryTask({
              url: "http://xxx/ags/rest/services/xxx/xxx/FeatureServer/1"
          });
          var query = new Query();
          query.outFields = ["*"];

const queryRel = new RelationshipQuery({
              outFields: ["*"],
              relationshipId: 0,
              returnGeometry: true
});

 queryTask.executeForIds({  
                  where: "id <> ''"
              }).then(function pokus(results) {
                  queryRel.objectIds = results; 
                      alert(queryRel.objectIds);                                      
              });

 queryTask.executeRelationshipQuery(queryRel).then(function (results) {                
                  console.log("queryTask results", results);
              });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, all the query task in the ArcGIS JavaScript API are async hence they will not follow the order that you are calling them in.

You will need to chain the promises.

You can follow the documentation on: 
https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/guide/working-with-promises/

Also, there is a sample:
https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/sandbox/index.html?sample=chaining-promises

All you need to do is chain the promises and extract all the object ID's from the response.